# npx create-react-app 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

I installed a new version of node. Now when working with npm I get the error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I tried adding environment, it didn't help. How to fix this? I'am user Windws 10.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure that nodejs is installed in the Programs folder inside c: drive ?

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan yes, I'm sure

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling nodejs or use nvm?

nvm not npm

Comment: @SharanBalakrishnan , I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled node.js. And I manually deleted the npm folder from the “c” drive. Reinstalled node.js. Now everything works.